# Bundling not working for webpage in subfolder

Tags: asp.net, bundles

I have created a asp.net webforms application using the vs2015 project template for asp.net webforms.
Now I want to use bundling, and it works for all pages on root level. But by the template, all user related pages (login, register, reset password etc) are located in the account-subfolder (e.g. ~/account/Login.aspx)

I created a bundle in the BundleConfig.cs like

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JQWidgets").Include(
      "~/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js",
      "~/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js",
      "~/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js",
      "~/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js",
      "~/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js",...
```

Before using bundling, I already had to include the scripts on the ~/account/register.aspx like

```
<script src="../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jqwidgets/jqxpasswordinput.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jqwidgets/jqxvalidator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

means using the relative path instead of the absolute path. Now I wanted to eliminate those script-tags by using the bundles included on the masterpage, but then those scripts aren't recognized anymore ("$" is undefined)

Trying to create bundles with a relative path caused an error (page won't load).

How can I use bundling (on master page or page in subfolder) for pages located in a subfolder?

Hint: I'm using OAuth2.0 Authentication, with all pages denied for anonymous users except pages needed for login process (login, register, forgot pwd etc.). Can that be a reason that bundle files can't be found?

Answer (score 1):

One more funny thing: It only didn't work in IE, but it worked in Chrome.

To get it work also in IE, I had to add the following to web.config:

```
  <location path="bundles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an app hosted in a subfolder. The way I got it working is removing ~ from this call on layout template: @Scripts.Render("/bundles/jquery"). When I had @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") it would place subfolder in front of /bundles like so src="/subfolder/bundles/jquery" without ~ it became: src="/bundles/jquery" which worked. I hope this helps.